# Multiple validate functions are treated as OR and not as AND

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to follow the **Field-Level Validation Example** from the official website.

This is my `renderInput` function that I use to render the field.

```
const renderInput = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta
}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <input
      {...input}
      type={type}
    />
    <pre>{JSON.stringify({meta}, null, 4)}</pre>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

This is how I call it:

```
<Field
  name="title"
  component={renderInput}
  validate={[required, minLength(10)]}
  type="text"
/>
```

These are my validation functions:

```
const required = value => {
  console.log('required', !!(value && value.length > 0) ? undefined : 'Mandatory')
  return !!(value && value.length > 0) ? undefined : 'Mandatory';
};

const minLength = min => value => {
  console.log(`minLength(${min})`, !!(value && value.length < min) ? `More than ${min} characters please` : undefined);
  return !!(value && value.length < min) ? `More than ${min} characters please` : undefined;
}
```

I am typing `test` on my input, on which:

```
if (required('test') && minLength(10)) // false
```

And what's happening is

```
if (required('test') || minLength(10)) // true
```

... because 1 of them is true, the validation is passing.

Shouldn't `validate` array be false if one of the elements is false?

Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to have `export const minLength = min => value =>`?

Comment: Yes, I import them from a different file, and I import it here. But that's irrelevant for the asked question.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. Why does `minLength` return another function?

Comment: sounds like you're asking if, conceptually, the word `validate` is appropriate to use here when it will pass when one criteria fails.  correct?

Comment: @Colin i think redux-form takes them as functions to test if they pass

Comment: @deryck, I am asking: if I pass `validate={[required, minLength(10)]}` will be treated as `required && minLength(10)` or `required || minLength(10)`.
Because what I see now, is that if I have the `required` function returning `undefined` it doesn't care about what `minLength(10)` is returning.

Comment: My console logs are logging these:
`required undefined`
`minLength(10) More than 10 characters please`

Comment: Is the form submitting?

Comment: what happens when you do what they do in the docs - put `const minLength10 = minLength(10)` and put that in the array.  just grabbing at straws though.  it should be `&&`

Comment: That actually solves the problem.. Apparently I cannot declare the function the way I was doing... :/ Can you write an answer with that to mark as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you do what they do in the docs - put `const minLength10 = minLength(10)` and put that in the array.

Comment: I believe it's that new function being passed caused a re-render of the element everytime so it was actually getting invalidated but wasn't showing in the UI because it was reset.  But without the rest of the code I don't know for sure.  Glad this works for you though

Answer (score 1):

From their example, it seems each of the passed in functions in the `validate` array are just ran sequentially and the first that doesn't return `undefined` (if any) will define the `meta.error` for that field.